# How to preserve the number of characters during a sed replacement

Tags: regex, replace, sed, pcre

How do I mask the following number like so in sed?

`account 123499029` -> `account xxxxx9029`

`account 12345` -> `account x2345`

`account 99999200193` -> `account xxxxxxx0193`

I'm using PCRE regex.

I know I can simply replace the leading digits with a fixed amount of `x`'s with

[`s/(account )\d+(\d{4})/\1xxx\2/g`](https://regex101.com/r/rO8dR5/1)

but I can't figure out how to preserve the number of leading digits.

Comment: Have you some magical powers to use PCRE in sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, sed doesn't have a pcre regex engine.

**with perl**

To have advanced regex features you can use perl in command line:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:\G(?!\A)|account )\K\d(?=\d{4})/x/g' <<< 'account 123499029 account 12345 account 99999200193'
```

details:

```
(?:                # open a non-capturing group
    \G             # position after the previous match or start of the string
    (?!\A)         # prevent to match the start of the string 
  |                # OR
    account[ ]     # entry for the first match 
)                  # close the non-capturing group
\K                 # remove all on the left from the match result
\d                 # the digit to replace
(?=\d{4})          # checks if there are 4 digits after
```

**with sed**

a way with sed consists to use a label and a conditional test:

```
text='account 99999200193 account 12345 account 99999200193' 
echo $text | sed -r ':a;s/(account x*)[0-9]([0-9]{4})/\1x\2/g;ta'
```

details:

```
:a          # define the label "a"
s/(account x*)[0-9]([0-9]{4})/\1x\2/g # replace the first digit after the "x"
                                      # followed by 4 other digits
ta          # if something is replaced go to label "a"
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to research more about labels and branches in sed..:D

Answer (score 1):

Normal or default sed uses BRE(Basic regular Expression).

```
$ echo 'account 123499029' | sed 's/\(account \)[0-9]\+\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1xxx\2/'
account xxx9029
```

In basic sed, capturing groups would be defined as `\(..\)` and also sed won't support `\d`
 pattern. You need to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` . Repitation quantifier would be defined as `\{..\}` in basic sed.

Use anchors , if necessary.

```
$ echo 'account 123499029' | sed 's/^\(account \)[0-9]\+\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1xxx\2/'
account xxx9029
```

Through GNU sed,

```
$ echo 'account 123499029' | sed -r 's/^(account )[0-9]+([0-9]{4})$/\1xxx\2/'
account xxx9029
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, sed does **not** support PCRE. Instead, check this perl's version of what you expected with your own regex :

```
$ perl -pe 's/(account )\d+(\d{4})/\1xxx\2/g' <<< 'account 123499029'
account xxx9029
```

Answer (score 1):

This perl command line should work:

```
s='account 123499029'
perl -pe 's/\b(account )(\d*)(\d{4})\b/sub {return $1.'x' x length($2).$3;}->()/e' <<< "$s"
account xxxxx9029

s='account 12345'
perl -pe 's/\b(account )(\d*)(\d{4})\b/sub {return $1.'x' x length($2).$3;}->()/e' <<< "$s"
account x2345
```

- `'x' x length($2)` expression fill letter `x` as many time as the length of 2nd captured group.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/[0-9](X*[0-9]{4})/X\1/;ta' file
```

Replace a digit  and zero or more `x`'s and 4 digits by an `x` and zero or more `x`'s and 4 digits and repeat until the condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{n=split($2,a,"");printf "%s ",$1;for (i=1;i<=n-4;i++) printf "x";for (i=n-3;i<=n;i++) printf a[i];print ""}' file
account xxxxx9029
account x2345
account xxxxxxx0193
```